# Can pygame detect the video mode of the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, pygame, resolution

Can Python and Pygame detect the video mode/resolution my screen is

I'm making my program run in full screen at 1920x1080 and this will work fine as I have a 16:9 screen @ 1920x1080 however if I run the code on a 4:3 screen @ 1024x768 then it gives me this error messgae

> pygame.error: No video mode large enough for 1920x1080

Can pygame detect the video mode/resolution of the screen?

Comment: Hopefully one (or all) of the three answers provided helped you with this issue. Don't forget to mark one as the answer and up-vote all that helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the actual size of the display, not the best resolution to use, you do:

```
import pygame
pygame.display.init()
# Before calling *.set_mode()
i = pygame.display.Info()
width = i.current_w
height = i.current_h
print("The screen size is: (%ix%i)" %width, height))
```

Then you can use width and height to pygame.display.set_mode()

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems pygame can detect various settings in your display.

The first place to look is [this link here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/DisplayModes.html), reading it should give you a lot of information on how pygame can help you with display modes. The *How to Decide* section will probably be most useful to you.

After reading that you should find yourself moving onto [this link here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info). You will see in the fourth paragraph after the links:

> If precise control is needed over the pixel format or display
>   resolutions, use the functions pygame.display.mode_ok(),
>   pygame.display.list_modes(), and pygame.display.Info() to query
>   information about the display.

So it'd be best to read up on how to use and play around with them to see how the information is returned and used.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `(0, 0)` or nothing as the resolution to [`pygame.display.set_mode`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), pygame will use the resolution of your monitor (if `display.set_mode` was called before, it will use the resolution of your current display). You could also call `pygame.display.list_modes()` and pick one of the returned resolutions.

BTW, in Windows you need to take care, because the pygame window could be stretched. [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/105820) will help.